# Calculate Average from Groups

Tags: excel

I'm trying to take a table of web data (average % of page viewed) and create an average.

This is what my table looks like:

```
 0-25%     954,353 
 26-50%     58,569 
 76-100%     73,653 
 51-75%     31,011
```

I'm looking to calculate in a cell that the average across all is XX %.

Comment: I don't find this very clear. Please explain what you are trying to do, and why a naïve application of the worksheet function `AVERAGE()` is not sufficient. It would help if you explained what you have tried, and why it doesn't give what you want.

Comment: At a minimum, explain what the numerical output for the above data should be. I take it that you are looking for some sort of weighted average, but just what isn't quite clear. If you can explain what calculation you are trying to do with the above sample data, we can help you implement it in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

[image]

Due to a lack of more information, we do not know what the actual distribution of the items in the range from `0 - 25%` is. Hence, I am assuming that they all average out at 12,5% (the median). If you continue this line of thought then the overall average is nothing but an average of the medians or (looking at the formula) a `SumProduct` divided by the `Sum` of all items.

Comment: Your "medians" are not medians, they are the mid-points of the percentage ranges. Knowing the median percentage value would require knowing the data distribution...

Comment: @SteveES That is a good point. The data itself suggests that the distribution is quite far from being uniform. My guess is that the median for the first 954,353 is far less than 12.5%. A principled answer would be to construct a probabilistic model and then use regression to find which model parameters give you the best fit, but any such thing requires far more information than OP provides. This particular answer is in some sense the best you can do with the data given, and might even be what OP wants, but it is borderline meaningless.

Comment: As @JohnColeman said: assuming a Gaussian distribution (within the ranges) is all we can do with the given data. Yet, if that should be the case then this is probably the answer the OP is looking for and not too bad. Anything else would require much more information.

Comment: @Ralph Your answer is a reasonable stab at the problem, so +1. If nothing else, it could provide a starting point. To me the data looks more like the sum of two heterogeneous distributions, an exponential distribution for much of the data plus something else which clusters towards 100% for some of the data. Something very bimodal is happening. Most websites have the property that a very small percentage of their pages are viewed, but a sizable percentage of (presumably smaller) web sites are viewed in almost exhaustive detail.

Comment: So I do have the ability to pull in 1% increments.  With that then I assume that the sumproduct would work as above

Comment: @Topher  Pulling the data in 1% increments would of course be an advantage, and should give a slightly more meaningful answer (though any averaging of percentages is conceptually problematic, since the percentages are presumably based on different sizes, so that e.g. one website's 10% might correspond to more than another website's 90%). Ralph's approach should work with essentially no modification.

Comment: I would assume that the "real" distribution is a normal distribution with a pretty small mean (maybe 2 pages or something), with search engines scraping all webpages skewing the top end and making it bimodal.